# IBM MQ Queue Manager Signer Cert replacement

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq

It's been sometime since I did a SSL project I have been asked to work on a SSL project where there is a requirement to replace the IBM MQ Queue Managers signer cert from SHA2 G1 to SHA2 G2. Could you please let me know what exact steps need to be performed here.

Usually, a typical SSL cert renewal for an IBM Queue Manager involves raising a CSR and once the cert is received just add it in queue manager kdb and do a refresh security command on queue manager. Now as here the signer is changing from SHAH2 G1 to SHAH2 G2 do I need to perform below?

1. Add the new root SHAH2 G2 one in queue managers kdb
2. Add the signer equivalent SHAH2 G2 one in queue managers kdb
3. Raise CSR for new personal cert for the Queue Manager and once received add in the Queue Manager kdb

Once all done do refresh security..... Now once this is done all the applications queue managers where this queue manager interacts with SSL add the new signer G2 cert in their kdbs?

Or

I can just add the new equivalent signer SHAH2 in queue managers kdb and do a refresh security. Also add the same signer SHAH2 G2 in all equivalent Queue Managers and applications kdb and that should do?

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't know what G1 and G2 refers to. But in general, if your current certificate does not meet the requirements of an organization's policy, you will need to request a new one. There is no point of just adding a new CA certificate if this has not been used to sign any personal certificate - either this Qmgr's certificate or one of the remote entities.
Yes, you need to add the signer's (CA) certificate in addition if it is a different one which signed the new Qmgr's personal certificate. Also the remote entities have to add this new CA certificate in this case.

Comment: What you said makes sense really and I believe in a way it would be raising a new CSR request for the Queue Manager personal cert and with the new personal cert will need to add the new signer G2 cert as well and once done will need to add to all remote hosts